# Horizontal scroll header bar layout

Tags: css, flexbox

All:

Right now, I want to implement a horizontal scroll header bar. The layout I used is:

```
<div id="header_cnt">
    <div id="header_mn">
        <div class="mn_item">KWD1</div>
        <div class="mn_item">KWD2</div>
        <div class="mn_item">KWD3</div>
        <div class="mn_item">KWD4</div>
        <div class="mn_item">KWD5</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the style:

```
#header_cnt {
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    position: fixed;
}

#header_mn {
    background-color: lightyellow;
    width:100%;
    height:60px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding:0px;
}

#header_mn .mn_item {
    display:inline-block;
    width:200px;
}
```

The effect I want for first step is:
The header menu fix to top, and all menu items sit in one line and the overflow part get hidden rather than wrap to next line.

**[UPDATE] I figure out myself, the way I find out is using FLEXBOX:**
Forget structure above,just use some new but similar structure:

```
    <head>
        <style>
        body, html {
            padding:0px;
            margin:0px;
        }
            section {
                border: 1px solid gray;
                /*padding: 1em;*/
                height:300px;
                width:100%;

                display: flex;
                flex-direction: row;
                align-items: flex-start;
                justify-content:flex-start;

                position:fixed;
                overflow: auto;
            }
            div {
                min-width: 250px;
                height: 50px;
                border: 1px solid steelblue;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <section>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
            <div></div>
        </section>
</body>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could use flexbox to create this header, check it out [here](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yyMOrQ)  You can also check out flexbox [here](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox)

CSS

```
#header_cnt {
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  position: fixed;
  background:#d7d7d7;
}

#header_mn {
  background-color: beige;
  width:100%;
  height:60px;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding:0px;
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
  justify-content:space-around;
}
#header_mn .mn_item:first-child{
  margin-left:10%;
}
#header_mn .mn_item {
  display:inline-block;
  width:200px;
  align-self:center;
  justify-content:center;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for help. Your effect looks amazing, I like that very much. But I am afraid that my desired effect more like what this question describe( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23075544/creating-a-horizontally-scrolling-menu-bar ), I do not want to auto resize the width of item(just hide those item go out of the #header_mn), instead I want to use scroll to move the hidden item.

Comment: Hi, Justin, thanks for your inspiration, I finally find out a way to make it work(even I am not sure if this is compitable for other browser, but it works in Chrome), I guess most of code is same as yours, only the very crucial part which is a little diff is: I set a min-width rather than width to item inside a flexbox, cos the fixed width seems does not work

Answer (score 0):

You need to    float:left on those .mn_item

I still don't have Reputation to comment, so here is my tip.

You can set min-width of #header_mn to a multiple of .mn_item.

Comment: Thanks for reply.  The float is the first thought out of my mind, but it will wrap to second line once the total width of  mn_item exceed the width of header_mn.